# Best way to store, elaborate and query raster data

Tags: postgis, raster, grass-gis, spatial-statistics, zonal-statistics

I have created multiple raster images with GRASS-GIS (~150Gb), that I'll need to multiply for a certain coefficient, and query the results that need to by saved just temporally. The portions of the raster image that need to be queried are identified by the selection of some polygons contained in a multiple polygon vector. The queried data then need to be elaborated by a simple python script for each of the selected polygons and return the result in a geojson format.

Which is the best way and tools for this operation?